# Car not getting electricity

Tags: ford, starting, expedition

I drive a 2003 Expedition. Last night it wouldn’t start on its own and I had to get my dad to jump it with his F150. It ran completely fine other than the lights being a little dim and flickering, along with my dashboard. As soon as I shut the power off, it wouldn’t start without a jump and nothing will work, down to not being able to unlock the doors. I had the battery tested and it’s at 89% charge so the battery and alternator are both fine. Is there a fuse it could be? I know my starter is going out because it makes that awful screech sometimes instead of starting and I have to let it sit for a few seconds before trying again and it successfully starting, but I don’t think that would cause my power to just not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the terminals that attach to the battery itself. Perhaps the jump loosened the connection just enough to prevent power flow. You can check with multimeter or by just wiggling terminals